# jQuery ajax request with mutiple part custom headers?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a basic ajax request that I'm trying to attach a custom header to with:

```
_auth=1,[my_apikey],
```

I can use postman with the same request, and it correctly returns a json response. The request is failing with a `401: Unauthorized`, so I'm believe that my headers are not being attached correctly.

#### How do you correctly add multipart custom headers to an ajax request?

Full ajax request:

```
$(function(){
   $.ajax({
        url: "https://r-test.ordr.in/dl/ASAP/10012/New%20York/568%20Broadway?_auth=1,3EJjhE07gEYumzByF9hM0c3q7xjf1ZiZOOwngk1MCoU",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        headers: {"X-NAAMA-CLIENT-AUTHENTICATION": "id='[my_apikey]', version='1'"},
        success: function(response){alert(response)},
        error: function(jqXHR, status, error){alert(error)}
    });
});
```

Request headers from dev tools:

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:SS_MID=14f520bc-d926-4ff3-a5cc-f5c682b758f5hrl1wmzt; ss_cid=cc24fc87-e81d-4ed6-a313-24e04cfbfd72; __utma=86046534.1735612382.1392236906.1392746695.1392826972.3; __utmc=86046534; __utmz=86046534.1392236906.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); __auc=2a449d7614427c94751a82169e5
Host:r-test.ordr.in
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8000/curate/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
```

Example postman response:

```
[
    {
        "id": 32096,
        "na": "Nuchas",
        "cs_phone": "212-363-0120",
        "rds_info": {
            "id": 186,
            "name": "delivery.com",
            "logo": ""
        },
        "services": {
            "deliver": {
                "time": 2865,
                "mino": 144,
                "can": 0
            }
        },
        "allow_tip": 1,
        "allow_asap": 1,
        "cu": [
            "Empanadas"
        ],
        "addr": "1514 Broadway, New York, NY",
        "full_addr": {
            "addr": "1514 Broadway",
            "addr2": "",
            "city": "New York",
            "state": "NY",
            "postal_code": "10036-4002"
        },
        "city": "New York",
        "latitude": 40.757627,
        "longitude": -73.985512,
        "del": 2865,
        "mino": 144,
        "is_delivering": 0
    },
]
```

Comment: can you check the request headers using the browser developer tool's network tab

Comment: @ArunPJohny updated with the headers

Comment: why are you using jsonp? if so I think you might be out of luck see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927610/how-to-add-custom-header-in-ajax-request-for-cross-domain-jsonp-call

Comment: @ArunPJohny Updated with workaround for setting headers. I'm using jsonp so that I can get around the access control origin.

Comment: still the question is whether the server supports jsonp

Comment: @ArunPJohny it returns jsonp in postman. is that evidence enough?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48012/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-agconti)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can make a ajax call to the said resource because jsonp does not allow custom headers and the said resource is not supporting CORS...

So the only feasible solution I can see is to make your web server act as a proxy, where by you sent an ajax request to your webserver which makes a call to the remote resource to fetch the values, once it is fetched the server can return the result to the client.

Also since the remote resource is a secured one with an API key it will not be wise to sent the key to the client side as anybody can see it and use it.