# $http.jsonp doesn't work as expected - always return 401 error

Tags: json, angularjs, http-status-code-404, http-get, http-status-code-401

I am trying to use `$http.jsonp` to get a json format string from server, but it always reports `404 error`. When I use `Fidder` to intercept it, I found it report `401 error`.

Meanwhile, I found it works correctly when I used `$http.get`.

```
var jsonpUrl = "http://SHABVJ7S12/versioning/history?orderBy=0&callback=JSON_CALLBACK";
$http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Basic TldEOEtLSDk4R0VKOkI4a3hld2JJeDdNcDlQdVFJc2t6aEh2NjF6cyUzRA==';
$http.jsonp(jsonpUrl, {}).success(function (data, status) {
    alert('succ ' + status);
}).error(function (data, status) {
    alert('err ' + status);
});
}
```

I am confused why it reports `401 error`, but returns okay when using `$http.get` with the same Authorization info.

Why does `$http.jsonp` always return `401 error` whereas `$http.get` works fine even if they use the same customer header?

Comment: What is the question you are trying to ask?

Comment: Jason understood my question correctly. My question is why $http.jsonp always return 401 error, but $http.get works fine even if they use the same customer header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't send custom headers (like the authorization header) when using JSONP ([another SO post about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13927610/how-to-add-custom-header-in-ajax-request-for-cross-domain-jsonp-call)). The target web service should have some other way to authenticate than by headers if it supports JSONP. That method is going to be specific to that service.

You should prefer not using JSONP unless you have to due to target service not supporting [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) or if you need to support older browsers not supporting CORS.

The best way to get around the limitations of CORS, if that is an issue, is to build a proxy on YOUR server that makes calls to the target server with the appropriate headers. That way your web clients can access your server without any restrictions and your server can access the remote API without any restrictions.

Comment: Thank you very much, that is something I did not know before. I just wanted to use JsonP to bypass the limitation of CORS. I searched it on web, someone says JsonP is a simple way to do that and there is no necessary to change anything on server side.

Comment: That's not true at all, the target webservice has to explicitly support JSONP, if nothing else, by implementing a "callback" parameter, and in deeper cases, by solving the authentication problem.

Comment: The best way to get around the limitations of CORS is to build a proxy on YOUR server that makes calls to the target server with the appropriate headers. That way your web clients can access your server without any restrictions and your server can access the remote API without any restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

I think Jsonp is good when you just need to to do GET cross domain.
CORPS seems little of overhead of simple GET cross domain.
In order for you to ensure Jsonp works, you need send back the JSON_CALLBACK from server side.
Instead of plain json response , you would send Json callback function from server.

your server response should be something like angular.callbacks._0({jsonResponseData}) . In your server code, instead of sending jsonResponseData, you would create a response(basically concatenation of strings) as a response. Server code would be roughly like this:

```
var stringForResponse = new StringBuilder();
                stringForResponse.Append(callbackFunctionName);
                stringForResponse.Append("(");
                stringForResponse.Append(jsonResponseData);
                stringForResponse.Append(")");
                toString = stringForResponse.ToString();
```

Comment: Pramod, thank you for your comments. There is a little confuse for me now after reading your words. So what I can do in my case? It's a big appreciate if you would offer a sample.

Comment: In your browser response should be something like angular.callbacks._0({jsonResponseObject}) . So for this , in your server code, instead of sending jsonResponseObject, you would create a response(basically concatenation of strings) as a response.